# configure Oauth2.0 using java and spring

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I am trying Oauth-2 using spring and java. I am getting following error. When I am trying to deploy I am getting following error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#8a224d' of type [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8a224d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'oauthAccessDeniedHandler' while setting bean property 'accessDeniedHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthAccessDeniedHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 166 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauthAccessDeniedHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 172 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1070)
    ... 180 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:444)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractJaxbMessageConverter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.JaxbOAuth2ExceptionMessageConverter.<init>(JaxbOAuth2ExceptionMessageConverter.java:21)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.geDefaultMessageConverters(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.<init>(DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:52)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.<init>(AbstractOAuth2SecurityExceptionHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler.<init>(OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 182 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ReflectionNavigator.getInstance can't be found
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:94)
    ... 207 more
08:33:52,556 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
```

Here is my config file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd ">

    <!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->
    <!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
            parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
        and what roles have access to them -->
    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_APP')" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>


    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
        combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
        credentials from DB -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="beingjavaguys" password="spring@java" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>


    <!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
        but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
        and other things -->
    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <!-- client -->
        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
            authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
            secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <sec:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
            http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</beans>
```

I am trying Oauth-2 using spring and java. I am getting error.

Answer (score 3):

The roout cause of your problem is :

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ReflectionNavigator.getInstance can't be found
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.Utils.(Utils.java:94)

there Utils tries to find the method getInstance of com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator, which cannot be found.

Looks like you are using a version of JAXB that does not fit your Java version.

Comment: I am using java 1.7 and jaxb-core-2.2.7